# copy rpi sd card on wins 10 (format problem)

Tags: pi-4, sd-card

how do I copy my rpi sd card using Windows10. I need to make a snap shot system disk backup prior to further development. I want to have an exact system copy NOT a backup of files etc. With a system copy I can replace a faulty system with a reserve copy & start again at a known point.   help please.

Comment: Let me Google that for you: https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=duplicate+SD+card+windows&atb=v297-1&ia=web

Comment: Welcome, but: *"I want to have an exact system copy NOT a backup of files etc"* -> Read again (I'm presuming you did at least try before?)  the accepted answer on the duplicate question which discusses **Windows and "Win32 Disk Imager".**  Note that this is repeated *ad nauseum* all over the internet if you search for "raspberry pi backup windows", you might have saved yourself all this hassle with that simple trick ;)

Comment: Hi Godilocks, take a look at Seamus's answer. Straight to the point & providing a relevant answer. Good honest advice, not the constant facile comments about wether the question fits the forum criteria or showing off inflated egos. My duplicate was to clarify my question for more simple minds. 18 unrelated answers to previous questions is just a waste of time.